# Internet Explorer Incompatibility - page just shows "[object Object]" WTH?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, ie8-compatibility-mode

When I click on a URL with the link "javascript:$('#dialog-modal').dialog('open');" in Chrome and FF my Jquery dialog loads. In Internet explorer 8 the page source disappears and is replaced with "[object Object]" .. WTH?

Comment: This doesn't work in either IE7, IE8 or IE8 compat modes

Comment: autoOpen works but it still wont open via the link.

Comment: yes it does work in IE8 you just need to know the tricks. see my solution.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is IE8 expects you to do something with the click event. The below code works and has been tested in Firefox, chrome, IE8. Notice you need the void(0) to make it work.

```
   <a class="dialogBtn" href="javascript:$('#layer1').hide();void(0);" style="text-decoration:none;color:#FFF">OK</a>
```

Or you can use this syntax:

```
   <a class="dialogBtn" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$('#layer1').hide();" style="text-decoration:none;color:#FFF">OK</a>
```

Answer (score 6):

In Internet Explodezor JQuery doesnt seem to work via hyperlinks. Therefore I encapsulated this inside a function and just called the function.

Edit: Seriously whyyy do I have to wait 2 days to accept my own answer....