# Internet Explorer Incompatibility v9 & v8 [object Object] ~ additional

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I am developing a Dashboard project, a component of which shows a summary table within a "minified" window on the dashboard, with the query parameters a user input to produce a particular report.

The code renders perfectly in Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer 11 and 10, Microsoft Edge and here is an example of what is correctly rendered.

[image: Correctly Rendered]

**However, some of my clients are still using Internet Explorer 9 and 8 and I must support them with code that is compatible and it's with these versions that I have problems as the following example shows.**

[image: Incorrectly Rendered]

**So, as you can see, for each user input object, for some reason [object Object] is displayed above in the summary table.**

The user input variables are stored as a hidden  tag, and example below

[image: Hidden Input Variables]

The process is as follows

1) I populate the table by passing the stored input variables to the server and return a JSON object with the results

```
 $.getJSON('/analyticsdashboard/SysoutSearch/GetSysout?' + $('#hdnParameters').val().slice($('#hdnParameters').val().indexOf('?') + 1)).done(function (result) {
            var tbl = $("#tbl");
            var tbody = $('#tbl>tbody');
```

2) I then and 'strip' out the variables into specific objects

```
var jobName = getURLParameterForHtml('jobName', $('#hdnParameters').val());
            var startDate = getURLParameterForHtml('startDate', $('#hdnParameters').val());
            var startTime = getURLParameterForHtml('startTime', $('#hdnParameters').val());
            var endDate = getURLParameterForHtml('endDate', $('#hdnParameters').val());
            var endTime = getURLParameterForHtml('endTime', $('#hdnParameters').val());
            var lastxDays = getURLParameterForHtml('lastxDays', $('#hdnParameters').val());
            var tableName = getURLParameterForHtml('tableName', $('#hdnParameters').val());
            var groupName = getURLParameterForHtml('groupName', $('#hdnParameters').val());
            var applicationName = getURLParameterForHtml('applicationName', $('#hdnParameters').val());
            var memberName = getURLParameterForHtml('memberName', $('#hdnParameters').val());
            var owner = getURLParameterForHtml('owner', $('#hdnParameters').val());
            var nodeId = getURLParameterForHtml('nodeId', $('#hdnParameters').val());
            var endStatus = getURLParameterForHtml('endStatus', $('#hdnParameters').val());
            var serverName = getURLParameterForHtml('serverName', $('#hdnParameters').val());
            var orderId = getURLParameterForHtml('orderId', $('#hdnParameters').val());
```

The getUrlParameter function below

```
var getUrlParameter = function (sParam, url) {
//debugger;
//window.location.search
var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(url.substring(1)),
    sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
    sParameterName,
    i;

for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
    sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

    if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
        return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
    }
}
```

};

3) I then test for objects that contain data i.e. are not empty and append them as a row into the summary table body, an example below

```
 if (jobName[1]) {
                        var newRow = "<tr><td></td><td>" + "Job Name" + "</td>" + "<td>" + jobName[1] + "<td></td></tr>" + tbody.append(newRow);
                    }
```

I've tried researching this here at SO, for example [Internet Explorer Incompatibility - page just shows "[object Object]" WTH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066733/internet-explorer-incompatibility-page-just-shows-object-object-wth)

But have been unable to find a solution or fully understand the problem.

I'd like to know

1) Why does this problem occur in IE9 and IE8 and not Chrome, Firefox, IE 10 and IE11, Microsoft Edge?

2) What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: I recommend spending some time debugging (IE9 has a debugger built in) or at least doing enough to create a [mcve] with a runnable on-site example (using Stack Snippets, the `<>` toolbar button).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was caused by my miss coding of the HTML to append a new row to the summary table.

Previously I appended each new row, for example, as

```
if (jobName[1]) {
                  var newRow = "<tr><td></td><td>" + "Job Name" + "</td><td>" + jobName[1] + "</td></tr>" + tbody.append(newRow);
                }
```

It was this miss coding that caused the problems in IE8 and IE9.

I've changed the code by splitting the new row and the tbody.append(newRow) into two separate statements, an example follows

```
if (jobName[1]) {
                var newRow = "<tr>" + "<td></td>" + "<td>" + "Job Name" + "</td><td>" + jobName[1] + "</td>" + "</tr>";
                tbody.append(newRow);
            }
```

and my "minified" window now renders correctly in IE8 > IE11, Microsoft Edge, Chrome and Firefox.

[image: Okay in IE8 and IE9]